# When Creating a Loop for Excel Sheets in R a New Column a new sheet is getting introduced

Tags: r, loops

So, this worked for 3-4 of the data frames I created this way, so I'm confused about what's wrong this time. The idea is that I have an Excel file with 12 sheets in it and I want to create a single data frame from all of them.

The EXCEL file I'm reading in only has 12 sheets in it, but when I get a print out of , it shows 13 -- there are a bunch that are getting put into a NA category.

```
for (s in nd_2013) {
  
    xl_translated <- read_excel("EXCEL" , sheet = s,
    col_types = "text", 
    na = "NULL") %>%
    mutate ( sheetname = s) 
    masterdf_2013 <- bind_rows(masterdf_2013, xl_translated)
  }
```

Comment: What is `nd_2013` ? How do you get it?  and what is `length(nd_2013)` ?

Comment: Isaac, @RonakShah points you in the right direction. Check `nd_2013` and whether you read in an empty sheet from your excel file. The `mutate()` will create an entry for your "13th" sheet and the `bind_rows()` will "fill" NAs for non existing column values.

Comment: @RonakShah Thanks for your feed back! (Also, thank you, Ray.) So the length is still 12. I think part of where I'm getting confused is the creation of the object "nd_2013" In similar versions that worked, the first reference would look like this: "for (s in nd_2013)" with both "for" and "in" highlighted in blue. It created something that basically, lists each sheet in the excel file. When I tried to do nd_2013 <- "EXCEL_file_name" It makes things worse. Sorry, if I'm not explaining this well. Still new to all of this :(

Comment: Sorry, I realized I didn't answer one of the questions about how  nd_2013 was created. It was created by 

"nd_2013 <-  excel_sheets("EXCEL.xlsx")

Comment: Okay, so... and PLEASE correct me if I'm doing something obviously stupid here. I went ahead and ran the code again, but without the `bind_rows ()`. Just `mastered_2013 <- xl_translated`. That ran fine. Then, I added in the `bind_rows ()` with both mastered_2013 and xl_translated -- and that worked... I think...